# MSG 137: When declaring variales DECLARE/SET/QUERY must be run at the same time

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, ssms

Call me a noob -- or maybe I wasn't asking the right question, but I looked all over SO for a solution around why I was getting SQL Server's Msg 137 error even though I declared my variable.

```
Msg 137, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Must declare the scalar variable "@myVar".
```

There are a lot of questions out there that address this question but in different contexts and, to be honest, most people have much more technical issues when they get this error such as variable being out of bounds. **So this question/answer is more for beginners who are just testing out declaring/setting/using variables.**

These are the queries I was running when hitting the error. Finally, a colleague brought light to the issue (see answer below).

```
declare @myVar varchar(20);
set @myVar = 'hello';
print @myVar;
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the reason I was getting the error is because I was running the code line by line.

As it turns out, variables only exist for the duration of the query (batch), so once I ran the declare query, the variable had been wiped out of memory. [SQL Server Pro](http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/working-variables-t-sql-part-1) was able to shed further light on my issue, which talks about local-only variable support in T-SQL.

> T-SQL supports only local variables. A local variable is available only in the batch that created it. A batch is a T-SQL statement (or group of statements) that SQL Server parses as a unit. Each client tool or interface has its own way of specifying where a batch ends. For example, in Query Analyzer, you use the GO command to specify where the batch ends.

Also there are a lot of answers for pre-SQL Server 2008 where you declare and set separately

```
DECLARE @myVar VARCHAR(100);
SET @myVar = 'Some Value';
```

but 2008+ allows you to declare and set variables on the same line.

```
DECLARE @myVar VARCHAR(100) = 'Some Value';
```